# How to reorder items in h:selectOneMenu depending on a condition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to use h:selectOneMenu which can display items dependently on bean params. 
So if user has "Admin" role, the first item should be "Admin" and the second one is "User", or vice versa. 
Here's my code example

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{adminBean.role}">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{adminBean.role == 'User'}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="User"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="Admin"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{adminBean.role == 'Admin'}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="Admin"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="User"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

However this code doesn't work at all, the selected list is completely empty

Comment: where does the `param` coming from? is it a map ?

Comment: Here's my final code, but it doesn't work. I need only 2 options, but it show 4

<h:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{adminBean.role}">
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{adminBean.role == 'User'}" >
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="User"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="Admin"/>
     </h:panelGroup>   
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{adminBean.role == 'Admin'}" >   
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="Admin"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="User"/>
     </h:panelGroup> 
    </h:selectOneMenu>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve it , use two `f:selectItem` and alternate their values based on condition

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{adminBean.role}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{(adminBean.role == 'User')?'User':'Admin'}" 
        itemValue="#{(adminBean.role == 'User')?'User':'Admin'}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{(adminBean.role == 'User')?'Admin':'User'}" 
        itemValue="#{(adminBean.role == 'User')?'Admin':'User'}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, hope it works

```
<c:set var="role" value="${adminBean.role}"/>
 <c:choose><c:when test="${role eq "User" }" >
   <h:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{adminBean.role}"  >
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="Admin"/>
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="User" itemValue="User"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
</c:when></c:choose>
```

U can add a similar condition for `Admin`

Answer (score 0):

**PostConstruct solution**

```
<f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.options}">
```

.

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(){
    this.role = loggedInUser.getRole();
    this.options = service.getOptionsByRole(role);
}

public List<SelectItem> getOptions() {
    return options;
}
```

---

**Single line if-else statement solution**

```
<f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.role == 'User' ? adminBean.userOptions : adminBean.adminOptions}">
```

---

**Parameter-Passing solution**

```
<f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.getOptionsByRole(adminBean.role)">
```

.

```
public List<SelectItem> getOptions(String role) {

    if (role.equals("User")) {
        return userOptions;
    }

    return adminOptions;
}
```

---

**Conditinal getter method (not recommended)**

```
<f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.options">
```

.

```
public List<SelectItem> getOptions() {

    if (role.equals("User")) {
        return userOptions;
    }

    return adminOptions;
}
```